# Is the AndroidManifest.xml file inside AAR libraries always "readable"?

Tags: android, android-manifest, aar

So, if you have ever "poked" inside an Android `APK` archive, you probably know that the manifest inside it (the `AndroidManifest.xml` file) is not stored as plaintext, but instead is stored in an unreadable binary format.

But today I've noticed that in `AAR` archives (aka: Android library files) the manifest is not "encoded" and is actually in plain text and perfectly readable.

I am assuming that this is to facilitate inclusion in a project and subsequent compilation?

But my real question is: **can I count on this?** i.e: can I count on the fact that stuff inside `AAR` archives is readable and not encoded in the binary format that `APK` archives use?

The reason I'm asking this: I have a custom Gradle-based build system that scans and includes `AAR` libraries based on an input configuration, and I could make it much more simple if I knew 100% that I can just read the manifest from `AAR` archives directly, without having to instead parse the package with the `aapt` tool like I do now.

Comment: "can I count on this?" -- today, perhaps. While I would be surprised if the tools team changed the behavior, you can't rule that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on this.

If you think about what the encoded format contains, you will see that this is inappropriate for a library. For example the encoded format replaces textual string references with index numbers - but that can only be done when you know the numbers associated with all the strings in the apk.  By definition the library is not the full apk, so the numbers given to resource items cannot be allocated until the combined set of resources is known.

If you look at the manifest files in many of the aar files, you will see that they contain the AOSP copyright header as an xml comment.  Comments are another piece of information that gets discarded when converting to the binary encoded format used within apks, and although less of a deal breaker, it's probably good legally to retain this information in the library.

Note that it's not just the AndroidManifest file that remains unencoded within aar files - all the other xml resource files remain unencoded, for similar reasons as above.

Comment: Thanks, yes it indeed makes sense. Just wanted to double-check